# Вывод ответа через оператор if/else

Tags: xcode, if

Подскажите начинающему, плз.

Нужно прописать вывод ответа через оператор if/else. В обще, работа с DatePickerом. Задача заключается в том, чтобы выводить на label отсчет дней с сегодняшней даты и указать, високосный ли год. Проблема как раз в этом году. Формулу нашел, if/else прописал, но как-то неуклюже, нужно упростить. Сори, если уж сильно по-нубски.

Вот код:

```
if((newDate.day<0) && (newDate.year % 4 >= 1 || newDate.year % 400 >= 1 && newDate.year % 100 == 0))
                {
                self.dateLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d дней %d часов %d минут %d секунд прошло; високосный год",newDate.day*                           (-1),newDate.hour*(-1), newDate.minute*(-1),newDate.second*(-1)];
                }
                else
                {
                if((newDate.day<0) && (newDate.year % 4 >= 0 || newDate.year % 400 >= 0 && newDate.year % 100 == 1)){
                self.dateLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d дней %d часов %d минут %d секунд прошло; не високосный год",newDate.day*(-1),newDate.hour*(-1), newDate.minute*(-1),newDate.second*(-1)];
                }
                else
                {
                if ((newDate.day==0) && (newDate.year % 4 >= 1 || newDate.year % 400 >= 1 && newDate.year % 100 == 0)) {
                    self.dateLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"сегодня; високосный год"];
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((newDate.day==0) && (newDate.year % 4 >= 0 || newDate.year % 400 >= 0 && newDate.year % 100 == 1)) {
                        self.dateLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"сегодня; не високосный год"];
                }
                else
                {
                if((newDate.day>0) && (newDate.year % 4 >= 1 || newDate.year % 400 >= 1 && newDate.year % 100 == 0)){
                self.dateLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d дней %d часов %d минут %d секунд осталось; високосный год",newDate.day],newDate.hour, newDate.minute,newDate.second;
                }
                else
                {
                if((newDate.day>0) && (newDate.year % 4 >= 0 || newDate.year % 400 >= 0 && newDate.year % 100 == 1)){
                self.dateLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d дней %d часов %d минут %d секунд осталось; не високосный год",newDate.day],newDate.hour, newDate.minute,newDate.second;
                }
```

Comment: эпично, блин

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот функция для выявления, является ли год високосным, накидал на скорую руку, может быть косячный:

```
- (BOOL)isLeapYearForDate:(NSDate *)inputDate
{
    NSCalendar       *calendar     = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components   = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:inputDate];
    NSInteger        yearForDetect = [components year];
    return (yearForDetect % 4 == 0 && yearForDetect % 100 != 0) || (yearForDetect % 400 == 0);
}
```

Проверял на этих данных: http://www.net4lady.ru/kalendar-visokosnyx-let/

**UPD**

Короче, вот, дальше сами:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    BOOL             isLeapYear      = [self isLeapYearForDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1704067200]];
    NSDateComponents *differenseDate = [self howDaysToDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1704067200]];
    [self outputResult:isLeapYear differensDate:differenseDate];
    isLeapYear     = [self isLeapYearForDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1735689600]];
    differenseDate = [self howDaysToDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1735689600]];
    [self outputResult:isLeapYear differensDate:differenseDate];
}

- (void)outputResult:(BOOL)isLeapYear differensDate:(NSDateComponents *)differensDate
{
    NSLog(@"%d дней %d часов %d минут %d секунд осталось. Год %@является високосным", differensDate.day, differensDate.hour, differensDate.minute, differensDate.second, isLeapYear ? @"" : @"не ");
}

- (BOOL)isLeapYearForDate:(NSDate *)inputDate
{
    NSCalendar       *calendar     = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components   = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:inputDate];
    NSInteger        yearForDetect = [components year];
    return (yearForDetect % 4 == 0 && yearForDetect % 100 != 0) || (yearForDetect % 400 == 0);
}

- (NSDateComponents *)howDaysToDate:(NSDate *)inputDate
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate     *fromDate;
    NSDate     *toDate;
    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&fromDate interval:NULL forDate:[NSDate date]];
    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&toDate interval:NULL forDate:inputDate];
    NSDateComponents *difference = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:fromDate toDate:toDate options:0];
    return difference;
}
```